# Error during yarn build "TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'Context'"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, typescript-typings

I am trying to build one project and am facing issues during yarn build with react router types. Project is not mine and I do not have any significant prior experience with react or typescript but I need to build it. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

OUTPUT:

```
Failed to compile.

/home/marek/devel/builds/ob1/src/webclient/node_modules/@types/react-router/index.d.ts
(141,37): error TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'Context'.


error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
Makefile:185: recipe for target 'webclient' failed
make: *** [webclient] Error 1
```

Also attaching package.json provided with the project.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "obelisk_miner_ui",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/classnames": "2.2.3",
    "@types/enzyme": "2.8.11",
    "@types/jest": "21.1.1",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.106",
    "@types/loglevel": "1.5.1",
    "@types/node": "8.0.31",
    "@types/prop-types": "15.5.3",
    "@types/react": "16.3.8",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.0.5",
    "@types/react-redux": "5.0.9",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "4.2.7",
    "@types/recharts": "1.0.23",
    "@types/redux-logger": "3.0.5",
    "axios": "0.17.1",
    "classnames": "2.2.5",
    "csx": "8.5.0",
    "enzyme": "3.1.0",
    "formik": "0.11.11",
    "isemail": "3.0.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.4",
    "loglevel": "1.5.0",
    "moment": "2.22.2",
    "query-string": "5.1.0",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "5.0.1",
    "react-dom": "16.3.1",
    "react-dropzone": "4.2.13",
    "react-redux": "5.0.6",
    "react-router-dom": "4.3.1",
    "react-scripts-ts": "2.7.0",
    "react-typestyle": "0.3.0",
    "recharts": "1.0.0-beta.10",
    "redux": "3.7.2",
    "redux-batch-enhancer": "0.1.3",
    "redux-logger": "3.0.6",
    "redux-logic": "0.12.3",
    "reselect": "3.0.1",
    "semantic-ui-css": "2.2.12",
    "semantic-ui-forest-themes": "1.0.3",
    "semantic-ui-react": "0.82.0",
    "typescript": "2.8.1",
    "typescript-fsa": "2.5.0",
    "typestyle": "1.4.1",
    "updeep": "1.0.0",
    "valid-url": "1.0.9"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "16.3.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts-ts start",
    "build": "react-scripts-ts build",
    "test": "react-scripts-ts test  --env=jsdom --setupTestFrameworkScriptFile=raf/polyfill",
    "eject": "react-scripts-ts eject"
  },
  "proxy": {
    "/api": {
      "target": "http://192.168.1.41"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This could be a problem of dependencies. Have you tried to delete yarn.lock and node_module, then rebuild?

Comment: @StéphaneVeyret yes it exits with the same error.

Comment: So it seems to be a compatibility problem between react-router and react. I would suggest to try and upgrade at least one of those libraries.